# Animations not working

Tags: animation

Our pipeline is to create an anim in 3ds max (anim works when scrubbing timeline), export as an fbx to blender (anim still works), then export from blender to spatial.io. However something goes wrong with our animations 50% of the time and they stop working in Spatial. I'm really keen to know what it is that causes this! I know theres not a lot to go on here but just in case it is something common and obvious we're doing wrong! We've checked animation tick boxes so that's always included. Sometimes an animation will work successfully. But when we go back and adjust something small and re-export, it stops working. Could it be something happening with parenting associations in Blender?